# All the binary n-words without the sequence 011

Tags: combinatorics, proof-verification, recurrence-relations

I'm trying to find a recurrence relation for the binary words of length $n$ that don't contain the sequence $011$, my attempt is as follow:

denote $f\left(n\right)$
  as the number of such sequences.

The first observation is that there is only one possibility for a sequence of length $n\geq2$ ending in $11$. For $n=2$ it is obvious, and inductively, if the same is true for some $n$, then looking at a sequence of length $n+1$ ending in $11$, so that $011$ won't appear it must end in $111$, but then we have a sequence of length $n$ ending in $11$, which by our hypothesis there is only one possibility.

Now if we have a legal sequence of length $n-1$, we can append $0$ at the end to get a legal sequence of length $n$. If we want to append $1$ there are two possibilities, either we have legal sequences of length $n-2$ and append $01$ at the end, or we want to append $11$, which as we've seen there is only one possibility. This shows us that $$f\left(n\right)=f\left(n-1\right)+f\left(n-2\right)+1$$

Though honestly I don't think my arguments in the second paragraph are correct. Not sure how to justify them anyway..

Comment: That looks right.

Comment: i can do it with two relations $f=\begin{cases} O g \\ 1 f \\ \end{cases}$  $g=\begin{cases} O g \\ 10 g \\ \end{cases}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your argument is fine. To put it a little more clearly, for $\ n\ge2\ $ the number of legal sequences of length $\ n\ $ is $f(n-1)+f(n-2)+1$ because there are exactly $f(n-1)$ legal sequences of length $n$ ending with $0,\ f(n-2)$ ending with $01,$ and just one ending with $11.$ A legal sequence ending with $11$ must be all $1$'s because, if it had any $0$'s, then the rightmost $0$ would be the start of a $011.$

Comment: To offer another way to think about this, consider the set $S_n$ of these sequences of length $n$ (so $f(n)=|S_n|$). Then define $A_n$, $B_n$, and $C_n$ to be the subsets of $S_n$ containing terms ending in $0$, $01$, and $11$, respectively. For $n\ge2$, these three sets partition $S_n$, so $f(n)$ is the sum of their cardinalities. The set $A_n$ is in 1-1 correspondence with $S_{n-1}$ (remove/append the final $0$); $B_n$ is in 1-1 correspondence with $S_{n-2}$ (remove/append $01$), and $C_n$ contains only one element, the sequence of all $1$s. The sum of these cardinalities is your result.

Answer (score 0):

- Taken two recursive functions $f$ and $g$ defined as.

$f_n=\begin{cases} 0\ + g_{n-1} \\ 1\ + f_{n-1} \\ \end{cases}$

$g_n=\begin{cases} 0 \ \ + g_{n-1} \\ 10+ g_{n-2} \\ \end{cases}$

-With $f_0=f_0=\phi$, the first sequence $f$ guarantees an optional arbitrary stream of $1$s, followed by the second $g$ which guarantees no occurence of two consecutive $1$s after any $0$.