# binary n-length sequences without 011

Tags: combinatorics, recurrence-relations

I need to find the number of length n binary sequences without the sequence 011.
my attempt was:

Let $a_n$ be the number of good sequences of length $n$ and $b_n$ be the number of good sequences of length $n$ such that if you add a $1$ at the end it will be a bad sequence.

So $a_n = 2a_{n-1}-b_{n-1}$
becuse each sequence in $a_{n-1}$ if I add a $0$ it will be ok, if i will add $1$ it will contain all the bad sequence of $b_{n-1}$,1 so i need to subtract it

and we have $b_n = a_{n-2}$ all the good sequences adding $0,1$ at the end

so we have $a_n = 2a_{n-1}-a_{n-3}$

i tried to find a solution for the recurrence relation, i got the following equation:$x^3-2x^2+1 =(x-1)(x^2-x-1)$ so $1$ is the only root for the characteristic polynomial but how do i proceed from here?

Edit: I had a mistake with the roots.The roots of $(x^2-x-1)$ are: $x_{1,2} = (\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2}),(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})$

So to conculde I get:

$a_n = (1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n + (1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n -1$

Comment: Looks less simple than that. Note that a sequence of only $1$s is a good sequence. Actually, good sequence are sequences that start with an arbitrary sequence of $1$s, followed by an arbitrary sequence of $0$s or $01$s (with an extra condition on length). Note also that when you are considering roots of the characteristic equation, you have to take all roots into account: even complex roots if there are any, but here $x^2-x-1$ has two real roots. Your factorization is wrong (or rather, the characteristic polynomial is wrong).

Comment: thanks i see my mistake it has 2 real roots, ill try to proceed from here

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1581976/all-the-binary-n-words-without-the-sequence-011?rq=1

Comment: i saw it there was no conclusive answer i finished the proof $a_n = (1-\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})(\frac{1-\sqrt{5}}{2})^n + (1+\frac{2}{\sqrt{5}})(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2})^n -1$